# Can an ArrayList contain more elements than the maximum value of int?

Tags: java, arraylist, integer, max, heap-memory

I was testing how Java (SE7) would deal with the `int` that exceed its maximum value through the following code:

```
int index = 2147483647;//the maximum value of int
long size = 2147483648L; //More than the maximum value of int by 1
int safeCounter=0; //To prevent the infinite loop
while (index<size)
{
    System.out.println("Index now is : "+index);//show the int value
    index++; //increment the int value
    safeCounter++; //increment the number of desired loops
    if (safeCounter==3){
        break;//to break the loop after 3 turns
    }

}
```

and what I got is:

Index now is : 2147483647
Index now is : -2147483648
Index now is : -2147483647

So after being confused by this, (which if I don't use the `safeCounter` it would keep going forever between the maximum value and the minimum value of `int` -- and no exception is thrown) I was wondering how would an `ArrayList` handle a situation where the the number of elements exceed the maximum value of `int` (assuming that the heap space is not an issue)?
And if `ArrayList` can't handle this, Is there other data structure which can?

---

Can you also explain the behavior I got from the `int` variable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How many data a list can hold at the maximum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767979/how-many-data-a-list-can-hold-at-the-maximum)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can an ArrayList contain more elements than the maximum value of int?

In practice no.  An ArrayList is backed by a single Java array, and the maximum size of an array is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

(Hypothetically, Oracle could redo the implementation of `ArrayList` to use an array of arrays without breaking user code.  But the chances of them doing that are pretty small.)

A `LinkedList` can handle as many elements as you can represent in memory.  Or you could implement your own list type.  Indeed, you could even implement a list type that can hold more elements than you could store in memory ... or even an unbounded number of elements if your list is actually a generator.

The fact that `size()` returns an `int` result (etcetera) is not actually an impediment.  The List API spec deals with this anomaly.

---

The behaviour of your code is simply explained.  Integer arithmetic in Java has silent overflow.  If you add 1 to the largest positive value for an integer type, it wraps around to the largest negative value; i.e. MAX_VALUE + 1 == MIN_VALUE ... for integer types.

Answer (score 3):

ArrayList can't handle that.Maximum limit of arraylist size is Integer.MAX_VALUE.You can use LinkedList which can contain any number of elements(depends on your memory actually):-)

Comment: Kind of obvious actually, considering `size()` and similar functions are all declared in terms of ints.

Comment: From docs : "Returns the number of elements in this list. If this list contains more than Integer.MAX_VALUE elements, returns Integer.MAX_VALUE"

Comment: What about the behavior I got from the int variable? not sure I understand it, Any Idea?

Comment: -1, Actually that's wrong. Even the `size()` in `LinkedList<E>` is of type integer. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedList.java see here for the source code

Comment: Its not wrong..But since ArrayList is backed by an array, we cant add more than Tnteger.Max_Value objects to arraylist.But in the case of LinkedList we can add.If it contains more than Integer.MAX_VALUE elements, it will return Integer.MAX_VALUE when we call size()

Comment: @MAK..From docs "The integer operators do not indicate overflow or underflow in any way".Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1 == Integer.MIN_VALUE.And then if we keep on incrementing it, we will be getting -2147483647,-2147483646,-2147483645 etc(because we are adding 1 to negative integer)

Answer (score 2):

From `ArrayList.java`:

```
     **
     * The array buffer into which the elements of the ArrayList are stored.
     * The capacity of the ArrayList is the length of this array buffer.
     */
     private transient Object[] elementData;
```

As it uses array in its implementation, you cannot index beyond `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, so that's a limit.

For the `int` behviour, you can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397475/why-integer-max-value-1-integer-min-value) question.

Answer (score 1):

This is because Java uses signed integers. ArrayList index starts from 0 and there is no way to provide a negative index to the ArrayList.

One possible solution to your problem is, first convert the unsigned integer to signed and the n use it in ArrayList.

You could convert the signed to unsigned by using the following snippet:

```
public static long getUnsigned(int signed) {
    if(signed > 0) return signed;
    long signedVal = (long)(Math.pow(2, 32)) + signed;
    return signedVal;
}
```