# Java Math.min() Error on Integer.Max_Value

Tags: java

This code, which should return the smaller of the two numbers, returns a negative number similar to the greater number:

`Math.min(15, 21474836477) --> returns -2147483642`

I suspected this had something to do with the range of `int's`, so I changed the values to `long` and the program worked fine.

I don't quite understand the seemingly random number it returns- why is it `-2147483643` and not the actual number I put in, `-21474836477`? Is the difference caused by the amount it overflowed, or is it influenced by the other parameter of Math.min in some way?

Comment: Please read up on int and check with the maximum int is: 2147483647. Look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html). Also read up on overflow. Your question is a possible duplicate of [why Integer.MAX\_VALUE + 1 == Integer.MIN\_VALUE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397475/why-integer-max-value-1-integer-min-value). Check out the answers. Also read up on [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). I am having trouble reproducing your result.

Comment: What is happening with the variables your using before calling `Math.min`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stated result, -2147483642, is 5-Integer.MAX_VALUE and also 7+Integer.MAX_VALUE. I suspect that the Math.min argument is actually that value, possibly resulting from evaluation of one of those expressions. Being very negative, it is definitely less than 15.

This program:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Math.min(15, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    System.out.println(Math.min(15, 7+Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    System.out.println(Math.min(15, 5-Integer.MAX_VALUE));
  }
}
```

outputs:

```
15
-2147483642
-2147483642
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
Math.min(15, 21474836477)
```

cannot possibly have returned

```
-2147483642
```

The code itself would not have compiled because the integer literal `21474836477` is outside the `int` [value range](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

It's possible you ran

```
Math.min(15L, 21474836477L)
```

in which case you would be running the overloaded `Math.min(long, long)` method.

Answer (score 0):

Math.min is overloaded as shown below.

static double   min(double a, double b) 
          Returns the smaller of two double values.
static float    min(float a, float b) 
          Returns the smaller of two float values.
static int  min(int a, int b) 
          Returns the smaller of two int values.
static long min(long a, long b) 
          Returns the smaller of two long values.

therefore you can even use it with long values for example

```
          long x = 98759765l;
      long y = 15428764l;

      // print the smaller number between x and y
      System.out.println("Math.min(" + x + "," + y + ")=" + Math.min(x, y));
```

However, your long range is also out of range