# Strange behaviour on dividing -ve int/-ve int ,in java

Tags: java

Although I am not new to java, I observed this peculiar behavior the other day. I was refreshing my basics by running code consisting of basic arithmetic operations. Now according to java (and basic rules of arithmetic's ofcourse) , `-ve * -ve` OR `-ve / -ve` is a `+ve` number.

But compiling this source:-

```
int b = Integer.MIN_VALUE / -1;
System.out.println("b:  " + b);
```

Gives me output:-

> b:  -2147483648

Which is `-ve`, Can anyone point me whats wrong? I know it must be small thing that I cant notice.

Comment: ```-2147483648 / -1``` => ```2147483648``` => overflow => ```-2147483648```

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk It's answer

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397475/why-integer-max-value-1-integer-min-value

Comment: funny fact: a good IDE will tell you about the overflow (just checked)

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk thanks , that was simple :D , but my IDE gave no warning. (eclipse kepler sr2)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To divide by `-1` is the same as negating the number.

Since the range of integers (-2147483648 to 2147483647) is 1 larger in magnitude on the negative side `-Integer.MIN_VALUE` equals `Integer.MAX_VALUE+1` which overflows back to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

```
System.out.println(Integer.MIN_VALUE == -Integer.MIN_VALUE); // prints 'true'
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an overflow. Per java specification, the sign is not guaranteed in overflow.

The overflow is due to the fact that

```
Integer.MIN_VALUE = -2147483648;
Integer.MAX_VALUE = 2147483647;
```

so -2147483648*(-1) is 2147483648, which is over the max value.