# Do not understand about some Java code

Tags: java

Today I met some Java code, but I cannot understand them, please see below code:

```
    int a = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int b = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    int sum = a + b; 
    System.out.println("a="+a+",b="+b+",sum="+sum);
```

And the output is:

```
    a=2147483647,b=2147483647,sum=-2
```

My question is why sum = -2?

Comment: For your second question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397475/why-integer-max-value-1-integer-min-value

Comment: By the way, don't edit your posts to change your question.

Comment: If reopened, now duplcate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397475/why-integer-max-value-1-integer-min-value