# Why 2147483647+1 run successfully and 2147483648 gives error

Tags: java, integer

```
int maxAgain = 2147483647+1;
System.out.println(maxAgain);
int maxAgain1 =  2147483648
System.out.println(maxAgain1);
```

why maxAgain and maxAgain1 has difference.

NOTE:

- maximum value of integer: 2147483647
- minimum value of integer: -2147483648

here maxAgain run successfully and maxAgain1 gives error.

Comment: The first one works because it overflows and results in the next value, which in this case is  -2147483648 but the second one is not allowed because you can't assign a value to int which is not in the allowed range.

Answer (score 2):

Because the integer overflows. When it overflows, the next value is `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. Whenever you add 1 to the largest java Integer, which has a bit sign of 0, then its bit sign becomes 1 and the number becomes negative.

In short, it's the same reason why the date changes when you cross the international date line: there's a discontinuity there. It's built into the nature of binary addition.

Sources:

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397475/why-integer-max-value-1-integer-min-value#9397510)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397475/why-integer-max-value-1-integer-min-value#9397536)
[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397475/why-integer-max-value-1-integer-min-value#9397506)

Answer (score 1):

Your first line overflowed, with a result of `-2147483648`, as seen [running on IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/KIIA5G). This is explained in the [correct Answer by Spectric](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66450555/642706).

## `Math.addExact`

To be notified at runtime of such an Overflow happening, use static method [`Math.addExact`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#addExact(int,int)). If your addition causes integer overflow, an exception is thrown, `ArithmeticException`.

```java
        try
        {
              int result = Math.addExact( 2_147_483_647 , 1 ) ;
              System.out.println( result ) ;
        }
        catch ( ArithmeticException e )
        {
             System.out.println( e ) ;
        }
```

See that code [run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/KIIA5G).

Answer (score 0):

An integer is capable of storing any number between and including -2147483648 to 2147483647 because it is designated 32 bits of storage.

You can use the `long` type instead, which can store -9,223,372,036,854,775,808
to 223,372,036,854,775,807, and 64 bits.